# Ошибка в условии

Tags: php

Возникла такая проблема, что если всё верно, то оно вместо 123, выдаёт пустоту. Где я совершил ошибку?

```
if(...) {
   ...
} else {
 if($param == 1) {
   if(...) $error = 'Вы должны указать ссылку на фотографию или запись.';
 } elseif($param == 2) {
   if(...) $error = 'Вы должны указать ссылку на фотографию или запись.';
 } else $error = 123;
}

echo $error;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(...) $error='...';
```

Вот эти конструкции губят. Не указывается альтернативный вариант. А вообще по-хорошему надо сделать первоначальное присваивание $error, тогда отследите изменилось что-то или нет. Потому что проходя по этим условиям вы не все варианты выбираете. Так
конструкция вида выводит 123:

```
<?php
$param = 3;
if(1!=1) {
   //
} else {
 if($param == 1) {
   if(1==1) $error = 'Вы должны указать ссылку на фотографию или запись.';
 } elseif($param == 2) {
   if(1==1) $error = 'Вы должны указать ссылку на фотографию или запись.';
 } else $error = 123;
}

echo $error;
?>
```

А если немного его изменит - получим Notice о undefined variable, который то ли omited у вас, то-ли скрыт:

```
<?php
$param = 2;
if(1!=1) {
   //
} else {
 if($param == 1) {
   if(1!=1) $error = 'Вы должны указать ссылку на фотографию или запись.';
 } elseif($param == 2) {
   if(1!=1) $error = 'Вы должны указать ссылку на фотографию или запись.';
 } else $error = 123;
}
echo $error;
```

Вывод: ставить альтернативные варианты во внутренние ифы либо дать начальное присвоение.
    ?>

Comment: @sctk, Вы как всегда правы. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @ModaL, обращайтесь :)